# C: is it possible to cast a uint64_t to const __m256i_u?

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, avx

I'm playing by writing with some AVX-optimised functions. I want to use a standard unsigned integer argument type like `uint64_t` instead of the 256-bit unsigned integer the AVX instructions require (`__m256i_u`). Is it possible to do the cast?

Comment: Is either one of these types a part of the C language standard?

Comment: What is the actual type of `__m256i_u`? From the `_u` suffix it kind of looks like it's a *union*, so you have better look what's inside that union. And what does the documentation say? What does your text-books say? Your tutorials?

Comment: at least in my c headers it is defined as `typedef long long __m256i_u __attribute__((__vector_size__(32), __aligned__(1)));`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the `_u` stands for "unaligned" in this case. gcc/clang use a pointer to this type as argument for unaligned loads/stores.

Comment: @Moldytzu You need to give more details, on what you trying to achieve. Do you want to put the 64bit integer in the lowest part of your `__m256i`, or do you want to quadruple (broadcast) it? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I'd like to fill the variable like this `((__m256i_u)value << 192) | ((__m256i_u)value << 128) | ((__m256i_u)value << 64) | (__m256i_u)value `, so it quadruples the value.

Comment: _mm256_set1_epi64x ? (the instructions are happy to take a __m256i, you shouldn't look at the implementation detail with _u.

Comment: Or if you are programming specifically for gcc and using a basic operation, `vec+42` automatically does the broadcast for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Intel's intrinsics API doesn't allow actual C casts between integer and vector types, I think not even between `uint64_t` and `__m64` (a 64-bit MMX vector).

Use `_mm256_set...` and `_mm_cvtsi128_si64`.  (And `_mm256_castsi256_si128` when necessary) to get value(s) into or the low value out of a vector, with a broadcast or a list of operands.  See [Intel's intrinsics guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,Other&ig_expand=1369,833,6404,660,6942,4375,4832,1979,321,630&text=_mm256_set) for `cvt` and `_mm256_set` intrinsics; Google the intrinsic name for examples of using it, especially with `site:stackoverflow.com`.  You might want to limit your intrinsics guide searches to SSE4, not AVX2, to limit the number of intrinsics to wade through.  And so the parameter list is shorter; it's more immediately visible that `_mm_set_epi32()` takes 4 `int` args, for a total of 128 bits.

See also *[What are the names and meanings of the intrinsic vector element types, like epi64x or pi32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911872/what-are-the-names-and-meanings-of-the-intrinsic-vector-element-types-like-epi6)* re: the existence of `epi64x` vs. `epi64` (MMX to XMM vs. 64-bit integer)

Also, use `__m256i`, not GCC's internal `__m256i_u` unaligned type.  Use `__m256i v = __mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*) ptr);` to do an unaligned load.