# In SIMD, SSE2，many instructions named as "_mm_set_epi8"，"_mm_cmpgt_epi8 " and so on，what does "mm" "epi" mean?

Tags: c++, simd, sse, intrinsics, sse2

I see many instruction with shorthand such as "_mm_and_si128". I want to know what does the "mm" mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See *[What are the names and meanings of the intrinsic vector element types, like epi64x or pi32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911872/what-are-the-names-and-meanings-of-the-intrinsic-vector-element-types-like-epi6)* for the element types.**

---

**The `_mm_` function naming very likely stands for MMX** or Multi Media, or the `mm0-7` register naming in assembly.  Intel starting this naming scheme for C intrinsics with the first SIMD extension they introduced for x86, [MMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMX_(instruction_set)), which used 64-bit vectors (in registers mm0-7, or the C intrinsic type `__m64`).

Officially, and apparently as a legal defense that lets them trademark MMX, it's not an initialism for something longer.  But unofficially it's widely thought of as Multi-Media eXtensions.

---

SSE2 added 128-bit versions of those integer-SIMD instructions, using the XMM0-7 registers (XMM0-15 in 64-bit mode) introduced with SSE1, which mostly added single-precision floating point in those registers, and some new integer instructions on MMX registers.  (SSE2 also added scalar and packed-double in XMM regs.)  See the tag wiki, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info, for more history.

Intel continued their naming pattern, like `_mm_add_epi8` as the SSE2 128-bit version of MMX `_mm_add_pi8`, not changing the intro to `_xmm_add` or anything like that.  As discussed in *[What are the names and meanings of the intrinsic vector element types, like epi64x or pi32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911872/what-are-the-names-and-meanings-of-the-intrinsic-vector-element-types-like-epi6)*, the `e` for Extended is what indicates that it's a a vector wider than 64-bit of packed i8 or u8 or whatever.

---

The `__m64` / `__m128i` type names don't seem to stand for anything, but the similar naming to `_mm_` and `_mm256` function names is clearly for association.

Comment: Thanks，your answer is very detail and has solved my problem.